# Cassandra PreparedStatement usage with ExecuteAsync can help improve bulk insertion?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am planning to ingest scientific measurement data into my 6-node cassandra cluster using python script.

I have checked various posts and articles on bulk loading data into cassandra. But unfortunately, none of the state-of-the.-art as discussed fits my use-case [[1](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-python-driver-multiprocessing-example-for-improved-bulk-data-throughput)][[2](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated)]. However, I found this post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33169945/7641555) which seemed quite helpful.

Considering that post and my billion of records data, I would like to know if the combination of using `PreparedStatement` (instead of Simple Statement) and `execute_async` is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work - but you need to have some throttle on the number of async requests that are running simultaneously.  Driver allows only some number of in-flight requests, and if you submit more than allowed, then it will fail.

Another thing to think about - if you can organize data into small batches (`UNLOGGED`) where all entries have the same partition could also improve situation. See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html) for examples of good & bad practices of using batches.

Comment: Regarding controlling the number of async writes, is there any parameter that I need to tweak in cassandra.yaml file? Or, should I use features such as Lock in my python script to throttle the behavior?

Comment: You need to count the number of requests that is sent (for example, increase when you send & decrease when you receive results) - if you send more, you'll get `ConnectionBusy` exception... In the `Connection` there is a parameter called `max_in_flight` that specifies max number of in-flight requests.